# Transposition definition permutation

Tags: permutations

My book gives this definition.

> A permutation $z\in S_n$ is a transposition if:
>
> - there exist $i,j\in[n]=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ with $i\ne j$, $z(i)=j$ and $z(j)=i$
> - for all $k\in[n]$ with $k\ne i$ and $k\ne j$, $z(k)=k$

According to this definition, is $(12)(34)(56)(7)$ a transposition? Because in his explanation he mentions that a "vast majority of cycles are singletons".

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Supoose $z = (1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7)$.

$$z(1)=2, z(2)=1$$

Let $i=1$, $j=2$

However $z(3)=4$ even though $3 \neq 1$ and $3 \neq 2$.

Hence violating the second condition.

Hence $z$ is not a transposition.

Transposition switches exactly $2$ elements.

Comment: Thx. I understood your point.